# A simple viewDidLoad question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, viewdidload

I have an app with a `UINavigationController` with a `tabBarController` and quite a few views.

My two main views, that correspond to the two tabs, both show a nice `MBProgressHUD` when they are loading data.  This is triggered from `viewDidLoad` and only intended to be visible once.  Subsequent refreshes from the server do not use `MBProgressHUD`.

The problem is, `viewDidLoad` is being called again in certain situations.  I believe this is because the view is unloaded because of memory constraints and then reloaded later, which triggers the code I only want to run on the first time.

My question: how can I ensure this is only called the first time they load the view, without trying to store a temporary count somewhere. All of my solutions seem horribly hacky. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL loadStuff;
```

in init:

```
self.loadStuff = YES;
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
if (self.loadStuff) {
  // load stuff here
}

self.loadStuff = NO;
```

Comment: See, now that was easy. Not sure why that didn't occur to me...was trying to make it more complicated than necessary. One note: because I setup the view with IB, initWithStyle wasn't being called. I leveraged the fact that BOOLs default to NO and just did my logic off of that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Only put up the HUD if you are actually exercising the code that takes a while. Then things will just work. Maybe something like:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    NSData* data;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)loadData {
    // put up HUD
    // start loading the data, will call loadDataFinished when done
}

- (void)loadDataFinished {
    // bring down HUD
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (data == nil) {
        [self loadData];
    }
}

@end
```